# List of open problems of formal languages

Tags: reference-request, open-problems, formal-languages

As we know, there are some open problems of formal languages. I am wondering if there is a somehow complete list of open problem of formal languages. If there isn't such a list, can we make it one as answer?

Comment: You might also want to try asking at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Now also at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18422/list-of-open-problem-of-formal-languages

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a link which describes some of the open problems:

- https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Talks/open10r.pdf

Comment: Perhaps related: open problems (as of 2010) on combinatorics on words: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/twiki/view/CoWiki/ImportantOpenProblems